# Search and replace partial string in vb.net code

Tags: string, visual-studio, replace, substitution

I have the following code as an example:

```
    A = 1 - A1 + 40
    B = 1 - B2 + 40
    C = 1 - C3 + 40
```

How can I use REPLACE in Visual Studio so that it misses A1, B2 and C3 and substitutes the rest with a different code, so it looks like the following code for example?:

```
    A = 2 *  A1 + 5
    B = 2 *  B2 + 5
    C = 2 *  C3 + 5
```

It's a simple example, but I've found myself in situationes where I would just like VS to only REPLACE a certain part of the code and miss other parts. I was trying to look for something like this:
SUBSTITUTE 1 - ** + 40 WITH 2 * ** + 40, if you get what I mean.

Comment: Just found myself with a good example:
SUBSTITUTE
`
   A.Data = (A5 + 40)
   B.Data = (B5 + 40)
   C.Data = (C5 + 40)
`
I would like to substitute A5, B5 and C5 with Z1, for example.

Comment: Like that? https://regex101.com/r/sNkNFD/1

Comment: That's great! Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect. If the answer was helpful to you consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

A regex replace would be probably the easiest and most flexible way to solve this, i.e. using the alternate `|` operator to define alternative characters to replace with `Z1`: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNkNFD/1)

```
(?:A|B|C)5
```

You could also alternate between specific cell coordinates in the same way, e.g.

```
(?:A5|B6|C7)
```